# non abstract methods of abstract class thread safe

Tags: java, synchronization, abstract

I have an abstract class with non abstract methods. I want to know if these non abstract methods are thread safe by default?

To make the question more clear, here is an example

```
public abstract Class Animal {
  private List foo;
  non abstract method survive() {
    //bla bla bla
    foo++;
    foo = foo * 2
    foo = nul
    //bla bla bla
  }  
  abstract method eat();
  abstract method sleep();
}

public class Cat extends Animal {
  eat();
  sleep();
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
  eat();
  sleep();
}

//etc etc
```

If both the Cat and Dog wants to survive at the same time, does Java takes care of it by default? Or should I make the Animal.survive() method as synchronized?

Comment: Your code seems to be non compiling and completely messed up.

Comment: Sorry I didnt intend to give a compiling code. I just wanted it to explain the question properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is no problem at all, because Dog and Cat are independent objects --> no synchronization problems...

Comment: Thats exactly my question. Does the Dog and Cat objets are independent ? Doesn't they use the same survive() method of the Animal class?

Comment: Synchronization issues arise if the same data, i.e. fields are used, not if the same methods are used.
Cat and Dog inherit the survive method, but the survive method acts in the Cat object only on the fields of Cat (i.e. foo), and in the Dog object only on foo of the Dog object. So no problem :-)
If foo were static then we would have a problem, as both objects can now access the same data structure at the same time.
That's actually the point: Check if some data are accessed by different objects at the same time - if so, use some kind of sync mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

Abstract class methods are not any special in terms of concurrent access. If you are working on a static resource in your non-abstract method then you should make it synchronize to avoid any concurrent access problem.

Answer (score 0):

If class A extends class B, then all the objects of class B can use public and non-abstract methods from A. Obviously, you can override this functions in B, but if you won't do this, then there would be no problem in using (public, non-abstract) functions from A.

Word abstract in A put in front of a method means, that you **have to** override it in the subclass.

Answer (score 0):

> "Writing thread safe code is, at its core, about managing access to state, and in particular to shared, mutable state." - Java Concurrency In Practice -

foo state is very important.

Comment: Can you please explain it with an example? I am pretty new to these concurreny problems and want to make it clear.